How to modify the legend level names in a two-axis line chart in ggplot2
I have the following two-axis line chart created in ggplot2:
#data
datos_graficos <- data.frame(
  Arena = c(20,25,30,35,40,45,50),
  Media_Mg = c(0.3050000,0.3025000,0.2775000,0.3157143,0.2887500,0.2928571,0.3225000),
  SE_Mg = c(0.02160155,0.02160155,0.02160155,0.02309303,0.02160155,0.02309303,0.02160155),
  Rangos_Mg = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
  Media_Fe = c(27.00000,30.25000,68.87500,67.42857,85.12500,63.42857,71.25000),
  SE_Fe =c(11.60294,11.60294,11.60294,12.40406,11.60294,12.40406,11.60294),
  Rangos_Fe = c("b","bc","a","a","a","ab","a")
)

#plotting in ggplot2
escala_factor <- max(datos_graficos$Media_Fe)/max(datos_graficos$Media_Mg)#variable de la izquierdo/derecho

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(datos_graficos, aes(x = Arena)) +
  #eje y izquierdo: hierro
  geom_line(
    aes(y = Media_Fe,
        group = 1, 
        color = "Hierro",
        linetype = "solid"
    ), 
    size = 0.8) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(y = Media_Fe, color = "Hierro"), 
    size = 2) + #puntos para hierro
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(y = Media_Fe, label = Rangos_Fe),
    color = "black", size = 3) + #letras para hierro
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(y = Media_Fe, 
        ymin = Media_Fe - SE_Fe, 
        ymax = Media_Fe + SE_Fe, 
        color = "Hierro"), 
    width = 0.2, size = 0.5) + #barras de error para Hierro
  #eje y derecho: magnesio
  geom_line(
    aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, 
        group = 1, 
        color = "Magnesio",
        linetype = "dashed"
    ), size = 0.8) + #linea para magnesio
  geom_point(
    aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, 
        color = "Magnesio"), 
    size = 2) + #puntos para magnesio
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor,
        label = Rangos_Mg), 
    color = "black", size = 3) + #letras para magnesio
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor,
        ymin = Media_Mg * escala_factor - SE_Mg * escala_factor, 
        ymax = Media_Mg * escala_factor + SE_Mg * escala_factor, 
        color = "Magnesio"), 
    width = 0.2, size = 0.5) + #barras de error para magnesio
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Hierro (mg/kg)", #eje y izquierdo
    sec.axis = sec_axis(#eje y derecho
      ~./escala_factor, name = "Magnesio (%)",
    ),
    limits = c(0, 100)) + #limites al eje y izquierdo
  labs(x = "Arena (%)") +
  #leyenda
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Hierro" = "black", "Magnesio" = "black"),
    guide = "none") +
  guides(
    linetype = guide_legend(
      title = "Elemento", 
      labels = c("Magnesio", "Hierro"),
      values = c("Magnesio" = "dashed", "Hierro" = "solid"),
    )) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(size = 12,color="black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14), 
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="black"),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color="black"),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color="black"))

The code above generates this chart:

Problem: In the legend, how to change the name from "dashed" to "Magnesio" and from "solid" to "Hierro"? The line drawn as dashed is actually for Hierro, the line drawn as solid is really for Magnesio.
Thank you very much for the help.

The labels and values are set in scale_xxx_xxx not in guide_legend, i.e. use scale_linetype_manual(name = "Elemento", values = c("Magnesio" = "dashed", "Hierro" = "solid")) and inside aes() use linetype = "Magnesio" and linetype = "Hierro" to get the correct assignment of the linetypes.

To do this you can modify the guides and use the scale_linetype_manual to map the correct linetypes to the correct labels:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# Provided data
datos_graficos <- data.frame(
  Arena = c(20,25,30,35,40,45,50),
  Media_Mg = c(0.3050000,0.3025000,0.2775000,0.3157143,0.2887500,0.2928571,0.3225000),
  SE_Mg = c(0.02160155,0.02160155,0.02160155,0.02309303,0.02160155,0.02309303,0.02160155),
  Rangos_Mg = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
  Media_Fe = c(27.00000,30.25000,68.87500,67.42857,85.12500,63.42857,71.25000),
  SE_Fe =c(11.60294,11.60294,11.60294,12.40406,11.60294,12.40406,11.60294),
  Rangos_Fe = c("b","bc","a","a","a","ab","a")
)

# Calculate scale factor
escala_factor <- max(datos_graficos$Media_Fe) / max(datos_graficos$Media_Mg)

# Plotting in ggplot2
ggplot(datos_graficos, aes(x = Arena)) +
  # Hierro line and points
  geom_line(aes(y = Media_Fe, group = 1, color = "Hierro", linetype = "solid"), size = 0.8) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Media_Fe, color = "Hierro"), size = 2) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(y = Media_Fe, label = Rangos_Fe), color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = Media_Fe, ymin = Media_Fe - SE_Fe, ymax = Media_Fe + SE_Fe, color = "Hierro"), width = 0.2, size = 0.5) +
  # Magnesio line and points
  geom_line(aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, group = 1, color = "Magnesio", linetype = "dashed"), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, color = "Magnesio"), size = 2) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, label = Rangos_Mg), color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = Media_Mg * escala_factor, ymin = Media_Mg * escala_factor - SE_Mg * escala_factor, ymax = Media_Mg * escala_factor + SE_Mg * escala_factor, color = "Magnesio"), width = 0.2, size = 0.5) +
  # Y-axis and secondary y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Hierro (mg/kg)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / escala_factor, name = "Magnesio (%)"),
    limits = c(0, 100)
  ) +
  labs(x = "Arena (%)") +
  # Custom legend
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Hierro" = "black", "Magnesio" = "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid" = "solid", "dashed" = "dashed"), labels = c("Magnesio", "Hierro")) +
  guides(
    linetype = guide_legend(
      title = "Elemento",
      override.aes = list(color = c("Magnesio" = "black", "Hierro" = "black"))
    ),
    color = FALSE
  ) +
  # Theme adjustments
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14), 
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black"),
    legend.position = "right"
  )



@rodrigo-saquicela does this answer your question ? If so please mark it as accepted, and if not please let us know why. Also please consider an upvote :)
